# What's the best way to specify a proxy with username and password for an **https** connection in python?

Tags: python, authentication, proxy, https

I read somewhere that currently urllib2 doesn't support authenticated https connection. My proxy uses a basic authentication only, but how to open an https based webpage through it . 
Please help me.

Thanks.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34079/how-to-specify-an-authenticated-proxy-for-a-python-http-connection, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/426298/how-to-use-the-httppasswordmgrwithdefaultrealm-in-python

Answer (score 2):

"urllib2 doesn't support authenticated https connection" False.

```
    # Build Handler to support HTTP Basic Authentication...
    basic_handler = urllib2.HTTPBasicAuthHandler()
    basic_handler.add_password(realm, self.urlBase, username, password)
    # Get cookies, also, to handle login
    self.cookies= cookielib.CookieJar()
    cookie_handler= urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor( self.cookies )
    # Assemble the final opener
    opener = urllib2.build_opener(basic_handler,cookie_handler)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [httplib2](http://code.google.com/p/httplib2/), which solves some of the limitations of urllib2 including this one. There is an example [here](http://code.google.com/p/httplib2/wiki/Examples) of how to do Basic Authentication on a https connection.